# Windows CE6.0 change registry requires two restarts when updating NK.bin file

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce

When I update my system with a new NK.bin file, I want to keep same language configuration I had before.

A suggestion was made that I read the information from the registry, then copy my new NK.bin file, replacing the current NK.bin (yes, you can do this while windows is running using that NK.bin file).
When this is done I write the values back to the registry.

My understanding is that this will affect the NK.bin after restart. This mean that the system shouldn't notice here that it is a new NK.bin file during restart.

And it works fine, the registry changes its value. HOWEVER, when I'm doing the update, it ends with a restart of the system.

When I login after that restart, the regsitry is changed to correct/loaded value, but it shows wrong language. Then after another restart the language is correct.

I want to handle this directly, making the system start with correct language from the start.

The code below shows last step of my update before restart. The new NK.bin file is just copyied and replaced the old one.

Should also say that following register is changed but wont take effect until the second restart:

- cSysLang = @"MUI";
- cDefaultLCID = @"nls";
- cTouchCalibrationData = @"HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\TOUCH";
- cKeyboardDefaultSubKeyStr = @"keyboard layout\Preload";
- cLangSubKeyStrCurrUsr = @"MUI";
- cLangSubKeyStr = @"nls\overrides";

  ```
     private void LoadDataAfterInstallation()
  {

      //langauge
      Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regLanguage = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(cLangSubKeyStrCurrUsr, true);
      if (!(languageRegInfo==0))
          regLanguage.SetValue("CurLang", languageRegInfo);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

First let's discuss how a persistent registry works.  I'm going to assume this is a newer device and it's using a hive-based registry (there was an older mechanism for persistence that worked in a completely different manner, but I've not seen much of it since the 4.x days).

The device has a baseline registry hive that the OS loads up when it's first booted (system.hv).  It then applies your changes (user.hv) to that baseline registry.  Now before either of these is loaded, the OS should be doing a checksum of the NK.BIN, and if it's different, it should toss out both and recreate them.  A registry from an old OS is not guaranteed to be valid for a new OS, and for sanity's sake they should never be used.

So the order should be something like this:

- Read registry
- Update NK.BIN
- Restart

  - OS deletes the old registry
  - OS loads the default language in the default registry
- Write your registry values for the new language
- Restart

  - OS loads new registry changes
  - OS loads new language

This, I think is where you are, yes?

The second restart is necessary for the OS to be able to see the registry changes you made. You *may* be able to avoid the second restart (I'm not sure - it's been years since I tested this and don't recall) by broadcasting a WM`_SETTINGS_CHANGE` after restoring the value.  As a definitive resource, look at the Control Panel source code to see what it's doing when the user changes the OS language with the UI.

Comment: The order is more like : So the order should be something like this: Read registry, Update NK.BIN, Write your registry values for the new language, Restart, Restart. I tried the WM_SETTINGS_CHANGE without effect. However if i replace the NK.bin file with an copy i dont need the second restart. But with the new NK file, updated with new stuff it look like i cant get around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MUI I think you can't avoid the restart. Some settings may be refreshed dinamically, but language isn't. But you can programmatically restart your device as soon as you re-imported the registry. Isn't that an option? You can include a key in the reg inside the image and change it when boot is completed. If you have the image value it means that the registry need to be restored. You restore it, setting the new value, and then automatically restart the machine. This should be a minor inconvenience for your users.